Monads and do notation with Props
I have several implications
def impl0: P0 → P1 ∨ Last := sorry
def impl1: P1 → P2 ∨ Last := sorry
-- ...
def implN: Pn → Last := sorry

and would like to prove P0 → Last in a succinct manner. To me, this looks like a good use case for Except and do notation. However, Except and Monad only accept Types, not propositions.
The best I can do myself is described below. Question: Can we use do notation? Or is there some (other) standard solution for this? (Eg. I searched for ?a ∨ ?z -> (?a -> ?b ∨ ?z) -> ?b ∨ ?z on Loogle, with no results.)
def Or.tryLeft (or: A ∨ Z) (impl: A → B ∨ Z): B ∨ Z :=
  or.elim impl Or.inr

def Or.throwLeft (or: A ∨ Z) (impl: A → Z): Z :=
  or.elim impl id

def lastOfP0
  (p0: P0)
:
  Last
:=
  let state: P0 ∨ Last := Or.inl p0
  let state := state.tryLeft impl0
  let state := state.tryLeft impl1
  -- ...
  state.throwLeft implN

Bonus question, if reasonable: Why are monads restricted this way? Could support for Props be added?

Related discussion: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/channel/270676-lean4/topic/Monad.20over.20prop.3F/near/286819212

After reading the discussion linked by @Trebor, I managed to write up a solution that does use do notation. It works by using PLift to make a Prop into a Type, and converts between A ∨ B and Except (PLift B) (PLift A) where necessary. I cannot say I find it more readable or succinct than the snippet in the question.
open Classical

structure Impls (P0 P1 P2 P3 Last: Prop): Prop where
  p0: P0
  impl0: P0 → P1 ∨ Last
  impl1: P1 → P2 ∨ Last
  impl2: P2 → P3 ∨ Last
  implL: P3 → Last

noncomputable def Δ (or: A ∨ B): Except (PLift B) (PLift A) :=
  if h: A then
    pure (PLift.up h)
  else
    throw (PLift.up (or.elim (False.elim ∘ h) id))

def Γ (e: Except (PLift B) (PLift A)): A ∨ B :=
  match e with
  | Except.ok a => Or.inl a.down
  | Except.error b => Or.inr b.down


def lastOfP0
  (impls: Impls P0 P1 P2 P3 Last)
:
  Last
:=
  let last := do
    let p1 <- Δ (impls.impl0 impls.p0)
    let p2 <- Δ (impls.impl1 p1.down)
    let p3 <- Δ (impls.impl2 p2.down)
    pure (PLift.up (impls.implL p3.down))

  (Γ last).elim id id

According to comments in the linked thread, there is not much of a reason monads do not accept Props, it just wasn't deemed useful as "a monad with type Prop -> Type can only be used to bind propositions" (link), which happens to fit my use case.
If it were the case that monads supported props directly, I believe we could get rid of the conversions and have just
def lastOfP0
  (impls: Impls P0 P1 P2 P3 Last)
:
  Last
:=
  let last: Last ∨ Last := do
    let p1 <- impls.impl0 impls.p0
    let p2 <- impls.impl1 p1
    let p3 <- impls.impl2 p2
    pure (impls.implL p3)

  last.elim id id

with an appropriate monad instance for Or. (But we could continue using Except.) I don't think we can get rid of the .elim id id as the do notation needs to return a monad instance and Last is not.
